# How to obtain the query string from the current URL with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, query-string

I have URL like this:

```
http://localhost/PMApp/temp.htm?ProjectID=462
```

What I need to do is to get the details after the `?` sign (query string) - that is `ProjectID=462`. How can I get that using JavaScript?

**What I've done so far is this:**

```
var url = window.location.toString();
url.match(?);
```

I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: @Cupcake: That question is about extracting parameters, this here only about getting `location.search`

Comment: Voting to reopen, the marked duplicate is a request for a library, whereas this question is about getting js code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 385, accepted):

Have a look at the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) about `window.location`.

The QueryString is available in `window.location.search`.

If you want a more convenient interface to work with, you can use the [`searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams#Example) property of the URL interface, which returns a [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object. The returned object has a number of convenient methods, including a get-method. So the equivalent of the above example would be:

```
let params = new URL(document.location.toString()).searchParams;
let name = params.get("name");
```

The [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) interface can also be used to parse strings in a querystring format, and turn them into a handy URLSearchParams object.

```
let paramsString = "name=foo&age=1337"
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

searchParams.has("name") === true; // true
searchParams.get("age") === "1337"; // true
```

*The URLSearchParams interface is now widely adopted in browsers (95%+ according to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/?search=URLSearchParams)), but if you do need to support legacy browsers as well, you can use a [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-search-params-polyfill).*

Comment: Just a note: always use `encodeURIComponent/decodeURIComponent` instead of `escape/unescape`

Comment: The first function `getQueryStringValue` for legacy browsers, doesn't work for

`?foo=bar&foo1=bar1`

If we try to fetch value for `foo`, it returns `empty string`.

Comment: Old browsers (IE) can use the [polyfill for URLSearchParams](https://github.com/ungap/url-search-params)

Comment: @Pratyush yes I mention that in the answer, with a reference to the more popular and more frequently updated [url-search-params-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-search-params-polyfill) package.

Comment: `const params = (new URL(url)).searchParams;` works for me.

Comment: You don't need the extra parens: `new URL(document.location).searchParams` works in Chrome

Answer (score 71):

Use `window.location.search` to get everything after `?` **including `?`**

Example:

```
var url = window.location.search;
url = url.replace("?", ''); // remove the ?
alert(url); //alerts ProjectID=462 is your case
```

Comment: Or even simpler: `let querystring = window.location.search.substring(1);`

Answer (score 18):

```
decodeURI(window.location.search)
  .replace('?', '')
  .split('&')
  .map(param => param.split('='))
  .reduce((values, [ key, value ]) => {
    values[ key ] = value
    return values
  }, {})
```

Comment: Good approach. Thanks. A lit bit fix it tho: replace checks the whole(!) string. we need to remove the first char. removing unnecessary loops. Result: window.location.search
      window.location.search.substr(1)
      .split("&")
      .reduce((acc, param) => {
        const [key, value] = param.split("=");
        return { ...acc, [key]: value };
      }, {})

Answer (score 11):

If you happened to use **Typescript** and have **dom** in your the *lib* of `tsconfig.json`, you can do:

```
const url: URL = new URL(window.location.href);
const params: URLSearchParams = url.searchParams;
// get target key/value from URLSearchParams object
const yourParamValue: string = params.get('yourParamKey');

// To append, you can also leverage api to avoid the `?` check 
params.append('newKey', 'newValue');
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use this for direct find value via params name.

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('myParam');
```

Answer (score 7):

This will add a global function to access to the queryString variables as a map.

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Add function for 'window.location.query( [queryString] )' which returns an object
// of querystring keys and their values. An optional string parameter can be used as
// an alternative to 'window.location.search'.
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Add function for 'window.location.query.makeString( object, [addQuestionMark] )'
// which returns a queryString from an object. An optional boolean parameter can be
// used to toggle a leading question mark.
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (!window.location.query) {
    window.location.query = function (source) {
        var map = {};
        source = source || this.search;

        if ("" != source) {
            var groups = source, i;

            if (groups.indexOf("?") == 0) {
                groups = groups.substr(1);
            }

            groups = groups.split("&");

            for (i in groups) {
                source = groups[i].split("=",
                    // For: xxx=, Prevents: [xxx, ""], Forces: [xxx]
                    (groups[i].slice(-1) !== "=") + 1
                );

                // Key
                i = decodeURIComponent(source[0]);

                // Value
                source = source[1];
                source = typeof source === "undefined"
                    ? source
                    : decodeURIComponent(source);

                // Save Duplicate Key
                if (i in map) {
                    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(map[i]) !== "[object Array]") {
                        map[i] = [map[i]];
                    }

                    map[i].push(source);
                }

                // Save New Key
                else {
                    map[i] = source;
                }
            }
        }

        return map;
    }

    window.location.query.makeString = function (source, addQuestionMark) {
        var str = "", i, ii, key;

        if (typeof source == "boolean") {
            addQuestionMark = source;
            source = undefined;
        }

        if (source == undefined) {
            str = window.location.search;
        }
        else {
            for (i in source) {
                key = "&" + encodeURIComponent(i);

                if (Object.prototype.toString.call(source[i]) !== "[object Array]") {
                    str += key + addUndefindedValue(source[i]);
                }
                else {
                    for (ii = 0; ii < source[i].length; ii++) {
                        str += key + addUndefindedValue(source[i][ii]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return (addQuestionMark === false ? "" : "?") + str.substr(1);
    }

    function addUndefindedValue(source) {
        return typeof source === "undefined"
            ? ""
            : "=" + encodeURIComponent(source);
    }
}
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use `URLSearchParams()`.

Lets see we have a page with url:

- `https://example.com/?product=1&category=game`

On that page, you can get the query **string** using `window.location.search` and then extract them with `URLSearchParams()` class.

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)

console.log(params.get('product')
// 1

console.log(params.get('category')
// game
```

Another example using a dynamic url (not from `window.location`), you can extract the url using URL object.

```js
const url = new URL('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xJ27BtlM0c&ab_channel=FliteTest')

console.log(url.search)
// ?v=6xJ27BtlM0c&ab_channel=FliteTest
```

This is a simple working snippet:

```js
const urlInput = document.querySelector('input[type=url]')
const keyInput = document.querySelector('input[name=key]')
const button = document.querySelector('button')
const outputDiv = document.querySelector('#output')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const url = new URL(urlInput.value)
    const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search)
    output.innerHTML = params.get(keyInput.value)
})
```

```css
div {
margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>URL</label> <br>
  <input type="url" value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xJ27BtlM0c&ab_channel=FliteTest">
</div>

<div>
  <label>Params key</label> <br>
  <input type="text" name="key" value="v">
</div>

<div>
  <button>Get Value</button>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this function, for split string from ?id=

```
 function myfunction(myvar){
  var urls = myvar;
  var myurls = urls.split("?id=");
  var mylasturls = myurls[1];
  var mynexturls = mylasturls.split("&");
  var url = mynexturls[0];
  alert(url)
}
myfunction(window.top.location.href);
myfunction("http://www.myname.com/index.html?id=dance&emp;cid=in_social_facebook-hhp-food-moonlight-influencer_s7_20160623");
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anupamkansal/2o4chd8b/)

Answer (score 4):

```
  window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

8 years later, for a one-liner

```
  const search = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(location.search));
```

Down-side, it does NOT work with IE11

To explain

1. The URLSearchParams interface defines utility methods to work with the query string of a URL. (From , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)
2. The Object.fromEntries() method transforms a list of key-value pairs into an object. (From, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```
// For https://caniuse.com/?search=fromEntries
> Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(location.search))
> {search: "fromEntries"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `search` property of the `window.location` object to obtain the query part of the URL. Note that it includes the question mark (?) at the beginning, just in case that affects how you intend to parse it.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the URL API that has helper methods to achieve this in it as the `URLSearchParams`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

This is not currently supported by all modern browsers, so don't forget to polyfill it (Polyfill available using https://qa.polyfill.io/).

Answer (score 2):

```
  var queryObj = {};
   if(url.split("?").length>0){
     var queryString = url.split("?")[1];
   }
```

now you have the query part in queryString

First replace will remove all the white spaces, second will replace all the '&' part with "," and finally the third replace will put ":" in place of '=' signs.

```
queryObj = JSON.parse('{"' + queryString.replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}')
```

So let say you had a query like **abc=123&efg=456**. Now before parsing, your query is being converted into something like {"abc":"123","efg":"456"}. Now when you will parse this, it will give you your query in json object.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Convert that into array then split with '?'

```
var url= 'http://localhost/PMApp/temp.htm?ProjectID=462';

url.split('?')[1];     //ProjectID=462
```

Answer (score 1):

```
q={};location.search.replace(/([^?&=]+)=([^&]+)/g,(_,k,v)=>q[k]=v);q;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
/**
 * Get the value of a querystring
 * @param  {String} field The field to get the value of
 * @param  {String} url   The URL to get the value from (optional)
 * @return {String}       The field value
 */
var getQueryString = function ( field, url ) {
    var href = url ? url : window.location.href;
    var reg = new RegExp( '[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)', 'i' );
    var string = reg.exec(href);
    return string ? string[1] : null;
};
```

Let’s say your URL is http://example.com&this=chicken&that=sandwich. You want to get the value of this, that, and another.

```
var thisOne = getQueryString('this'); // returns 'chicken'
var thatOne = getQueryString('that'); // returns 'sandwich'
var anotherOne = getQueryString('another'); // returns null
```

If you want to use a URL other than the one in the window, you can pass one in as a second argument.

```
var yetAnotherOne = getQueryString('example', 'http://another-example.com&example=something'); // returns 'something'
```

[Reference](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-querystring-with-native-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is way more safer to rely on the browser than any ingenious regex:

```js
const parseUrl = function(url) { 
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  a.href = url
  return {
    protocol: a.protocol ? a.protocol : null,
    hostname: a.hostname ? a.hostname : null,
    port: a.port ? a.port : null,
    path: a.pathname ? a.pathname : null,
    query: a.search ? a.search : null,
    hash: a.hash ? a.hash : null,
    host: a.host ? a.host : null  
  }
}

console.log( parseUrl(window.location.href) ) //stacksnippet
//to obtain a query
console.log( parseUrl( 'https://example.com?qwery=this').query )
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return query parameters as an associative array

```
var queryParams =[];
var query= document.location.search.replace("?",'').split("&");
for(var i =0; i< query.length; i++)
{
  if(query[i]){
    var temp = query[i].split("=");
    queryParams[temp[0]] = temp[1]
  }
}
```

Comment: Explanations or descriptions should be posted as part of your answer, not as a comment on your answer. I have copied your comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use libraries, **URLSearchParams** is not available and you are looking for a pure js solution, check this:

```
function getQueryParams(url) {
  const re = /(\w+)=([^\s&]+)/g;
  let dict = {}, m;
  while ((m = re.exec(url))) {
    dict[m[1]] = m[3] || m[2];
  }
  return dict;
}
```

**Usage**

```
console.log(getQueryParams("http://localhost:5000/admin/repository?name=acme-web&bbb=ccc"));
```

**Result**

```
{ name: 'asp-web', bbb: 'ccc' }
```

## Live Sample

```js
function getQueryParams(url) {
  const re = /(\w+)=([^\s&]+)/g;
  let dict = {}, m;
  while ((m = re.exec(url))) {
    dict[m[1]] = m[3] || m[2];
  }
  return dict;
}

console.log(getQueryParams("http://localhost:5000/admin/repository?name=acme-web&bbb=ccc"))
```

Answer (score -1):

For React Native, React, and For Node project, below one is working

```
yarn add  query-string

import queryString from 'query-string';

const parsed = queryString.parseUrl("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=10&limit=10");

console.log(parsed.offset) will display 10
```

Comment: that's not the current url

Comment: Hate to say it, but the guy is right... you say read the question then put comments... but the question (see title)... asks about the query string of the current URL "How to obtain the query string from the current URL"... and his example code... shows he is trying to get the query string of the current URL. `var url = window.location.toString(); url.match(?);`.