# Filtering Quicksand using Query String

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, quicksand

FYI I suck at javascript and can't wrap my head around Query Strings.

My question is regarding Quicksand
http://razorjack.net/quicksand/index.html

How do I modify the http://razorjack.net/quicksand/scripts/main.js using javascript to allow for sorting based on the given filters via an incoming URL.

Demo's given filters:

**Filter by type:**
        Everything, 
        Applications, 
        Utilities

**Sort by:**
        Name, 
        Size

So the incoming URLs could look like this depending on what parameters you use, overiding the default view:

razorjack.net/quicksand/index.html?Type=Everything&Sort=Size

razorjack.net/quicksand/index.html?Type=Utilities&Sort=Name

Answer (score 0):

That Quick Sand Plugin does not sort or filter objects , all it does it replace one list of objects with another , the whole point of it is the cool animation.

So you need to do the sorting and/or filtering somewhere else , probably best on the server side if the results are comming from a database , then put them in a list , then call the Quick Sand plugin to replace the current list with the one you just created

```
  function loadPageVar (sVar) {  
  return unescape(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + escape(sVar).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));  
}  

// Would alert the value of QueryString-variable called name  
alert(loadPageVar("Type"));
```

That is an example of how to get a query string's value in javascript from [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870512/obtaining-querystring-from-current-url-in-javascript)

If you don't have that many items in your list, then you could type all your lists out in HTML ahead of time , and set the classes to hidden, then based on the query string you'll know which one to show