# javascript get querystring

Tags: javascript, query-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [obtaining querystring from current url in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870512/obtaining-querystring-from-current-url-in-javascript)

I was to get everything after the question mark in the url. Ive seen a way to do it that does not require a function but cannot find it for the life of me.

url

```
fsdhfbsdfj/index.html?hello
```

get

```
hello
```

Comment: "everything after the question mark" and querystring are two different things.

Comment: See also [JavaScript query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string).

Comment: This is not a duplicate! Every other question concerned with accessing the query string *also includes the step of parsing it*. This one gave me the much simpler answer to the intermediate question of simply getting it unparsed.

Answer (score 31):

Use

```
var query = window.location.search;
```

If you want to get rid of the starting "?", use

```
var query = window.location.search.slice(1);
```

[The properties of the location object are described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location).

Answer (score 4):

```
var querystring=window.location.search.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your title says "get querystring", but your question says "get everything after the question mark" which is something different and can include both a querystring and a hash.

I assume that when you say "the" url you are talking about the current Web page.

To get the querystring:

```
window.location.search
```

To get everything after the first ?:

```
window.location.href.split("?").slice(1).join("?");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the query string in `window.location.search`