# Send Javascript Variable value to another HTML page on SUBMIT

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to send a Javascript variable value to another page on SUBMITTING a form.

HTML

```
<form action="po1.html">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="getVals();" />
</form>
```

JS

```
function getVals(){
        var e = document.getElementById("Features");    
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        alert(strUser);
    }
```

i have selected that strUser value by a SELECT OPTION menu, now i don't know how to send it to another HTML page buy submitting...
help please

Comment: Just clarifying - you're submitting the form to po1.html but wish to send the value within the select box to **an entirely different** page?  Or you wish to change the form's destination?

Comment: i just want to send strUser's value to page, TO ANY PAGE just through a onCLICK function

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="po1.html" method="get">
  <select name="selectnames">
    <option>me</option>
    <option>you</option>
    <option>she</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

the value of select with name `selectnames` will be automatically available on another site, you would catch it by its name on another page with GET or POST depending on which method of form you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on doing this with JS, then add it to the form using a hidden input.

```
<form id="myForm" action="po1.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', getVals);
    function getVals(event) {
        var e = document.getElementById("Features");    
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var hidden = document.createElement('input');
        hidden.type = "hidden";
        hidden.name = "foo";
        hidden.value = strUser;
        event.target.appendChild(hidden);
    }
</script>
```

… but it would make more sense to just put the select element in the form.

Comment: you didn't get..
i have value in strUser, now i want to send it to that po1.html page on submitting

Comment: Just tell me how to send a Javascript variable value to another page.

Comment: @JunaidFarooq — I did.

Comment: like you have a variable strUser having a value of 1
now print it to another page

Comment: @JunaidFarooq — You didn't ask how to display it on the other page, only how to send it. It is being sent. To display it, you need to pull it out of the query string. That is best done with server side code. Otherwise see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870512/how-to-obtaining-the-querystring-from-the-current-url-with-javascript

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59348/discussion-between-junaid-farooq-and-quentin).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**You have to set value to page 1:**

localStorage.setItem('val',strUser)

**You have to get value to page 2:**

localStorage.getItem('val')

Be aware, that not every user has a localStorage (older browsers).