# how to forward a link with URI to another link with the same URI

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api-routing

My program directs users to a webpage with their username and password. E.g. 
http://example.html?username=username&password=password.

Now I created another page in asp.net and I want some code on example.html to redirect the link to http://example.aspx?username=username&password=password.

So what i want is to get the URI from the first url and direct it to the new url by appending the URI.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the querystring in its entirety via

```
window.location.search
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870512/how-to-obtaining-the-querystring-from-the-current-url-with-javascript) with more about that.  Using this, you can extract the parameters, append them to a new URL, and render the link, or set

```
window.location = "example.aspx" + window.location.search
```

I believe search comes with "?", but I could be wrong.  I assume this is an exmaple; note it's not a good practice to pass the password through a querystring as clear text, especially if you are not using HTTPS.  It's generally advisable to do a POST operation, not a GET operation with querystring, when it comes to sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

Use window.location.search to get everything after "?". Then you can just direct the new aspx page using this java script line.

```
window.location = "example.aspx" + window.location.search
```