# How to fill observable from query parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm writing ASP.NET/MVC application. I need to fill an Knockout observable with value, which is being passed through the URL. Let's say, for instance, that I want to open the following page:

```
http://example.com/Controller/Action?param=test
```

I want to put the value passed through the URL parameter to input:

```
<input data-bind="value: field, <?>"></input> <!-- Either set value to "test" here -->

this.field = ko.observable(<?>) <!-- or here -->
```

**Solution 1**

Since I have full control on generating HTML, I can create hidden field, populate it with value, and then jQuery my way to the observable, but it seem to be quite an overkill for me.

```
<input type="hidden" id="temp" value="@Model.Param"></input>

field($("#temp").val());
```

**Solution 2**

Another option is to generate some Javascript with Razor:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pageViewModel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    pageViewModel.setValue(@Model.Param); // Dangerous
</script>
```

This is dangerous though - I would apply some security measures to avoid people injecting Javascript here.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the query string though javascript directly in your knockout view-model by checking the window.location.search [How to obtaining the querystring from the current URL with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870512/how-to-obtaining-the-querystring-from-the-current-url-with-javascript)

```
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
this.field = ko.observable(searchParams.get("param"));
```

(The linked SO answer also has a solution for older browser support if URLSearchParams aren't supported)

Answer (score 2):

I like Jason Spake's answer better but this is how we do it where I work...

we have a utility function

```
// this is a utility function that returns query string values. Pass in the
// name of the query string and the value is returned
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```

then we call it like this

```
this.HazInd = ko.observable(getUrlVars()["HazInd"]);
```